# TeX math markup is sorely needed

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mathjax, formatting

This site is going to need TeX markup to express mathematical symbols and formulas well.

Comment: Yep.
They have it at Math Overflow, hence should be easy apply it here.

Comment: For equations the site needs something besides image links. ∑∑∑∑

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I'm afraid this doesn't even get much attention at the [main meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12700/add-latex-support-to-markdown-wmd)... But maybe if we all upvote there, we'd get more attention - I'll attach a bounty there, maybe that helps

Comment: Whatever we are using now chart.apis.google is pretty horrible and I hope we can switch to jsmath or mathjax :S

Comment: We will continue to improve support for TeX - this is by no means the end.

Comment: ~~~~~ yay! ~~~~~

Comment: @Geoff: I'm not clear on this...what exactly was done?  I'm not seeing any change...I still see all kinds of $blah$ type stuff.

Comment: *~-~-~-~- **YAY!** -~-~-~-~*

Answer (score 47):

I have already started using TeX in my markup.

The way that Math Overflow does it is to surround the TeX with dollar signs, using the [jsMath library](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/).

I suggest we stick with that convention, so that when we have support for it, our old posts will "light up".

**EDIT:**

I have created a quick-hack grease monkey script to get this done in the mean time:
http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/81977

**EDIT2:**

I have updated the script to work on Stats.stackexchange.com, and have added in transparency, and options to use other services, as well.

**EDIT3:**

I have incorporated Isaac's changes, and added an additional rendering service.

Comment: @John: Is it ok to copy your script for the stats.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @Srikant:  I would rather have you just link people to my code, but the source is open.

Comment: @John: Will the script work as is for stats.stackexchange.com? If yes, I will be more than happy to point to your script to users over there. A second question: On what browsers does the script work (only firefox + greasemonkey installed?)?

Comment: @Srikant: I got it to work on chrome without other plugins. It should work for any site by changing the @include to the corresponding domain (idk if @namespace have to be changed)

Comment: @Mgcl: Thanks. @John: The image is not showing up in chrome but working in firefox. BTW, should we take discussions reg the script to userscripts.org?

Comment: @John: something in your update broke the script for me in Chrome--it was working last night and now produces broken images.

Comment: @John: Please see my modifications to your current (4th) version, posted at http://pastebin.com/uVB1rEdf and described below (http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2/183#183).

Comment: @Isaac: Thanks, I have incorporated your changes.

Comment: Does it work on Safari?

Comment: the script is fantastic :-)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution @John - we have incorporated it as a plugin on Math / Stats / Tex and all related meta sites for the good of the community.

Comment: Great to have this on the math/stats/TeX sites. However, it is occasionally giving odd results. For example, see the answer of PaulHurleyuk at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213/what-is-the-best-way-to-identify-outliers-in-multivariate-data. The problem is that the R code includes a dollar sign. Can the script by modified to fix this?

Comment: @Rob: Yes, easily. There is a list of tag names to ignore, and we can just add 'pre' and 'code' to the list.  Also, we won't be able to *entirely* get away from weirdness, because the code is not an actual parser.

Comment: apologies for hijacking this thread, but I was wondering how we might get this enabled on the new CS theory SE site (cstheory.stackexchange.com) as well ?

Answer (score 26):

The developers should come and ask the moderators of MathOverflow (e.g. me) about this, and we'll happily help out!

By the way, I'd recommend actually using MathJax, the brand new replacement for jsMath. It's still not quite as fast as jsMath, but it's the way of the future. MathOverflow will switch soon.

Comment: MathJax is written by the same guy, only it's built with *the future* (HTML5) in mind and supports LaTeX *and* MathML.

Comment: HTML5 is not the future.  It's a kludgy hack made by lazy software manufacturers who don't want to bother complying with XHTML2.

Comment: Future proof is important. I hope they'll use MathJax.
Thanks.

Comment: XHTML2 is dead, the group working on it was made redundant.

Answer (score 18):

## Temporary workarounds:

Images can be embedded in questions and answers with `![](http://www.example.com/image.png)` like so:
`![](http://mathurl.com/2azr28f.png)` becomes [image]
Combine this with:
http://mathurl.com/ - type in latex, get a minified image url to link to in your posts
http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php - as above, but no minification, and you have to rightclick to get the image url.

For simple formulas, where LaTeX is not needed:
You can use `<sup></sup>` to write superscripts and `<sub></sub>` for subscripts:
`y<sub>1</sub>=x<sup>2</sup>+3`becomes y<sub>1</sub>=x<sup>2</sup>+3

Comment: +1 for mathurl.com I never know about it.

Comment: +1. IMO this is the preferable workaround.

Answer (score 14):

I've posted [a walk-through of how we've implemented math rendering on MathOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57931/area51-se-2-0-site-specific-script-support-such-as-latex-in-beta-phase/58450#58450) on meta.SO. As Scott said, we'll be switching to MathJax in the near future, so it probably makes sense for new SE sites to just use MathJax from the get-go. Once we switch, I'll try to remember to update that answer to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 13):

We have added MathJax to support TeX equations based on feedback.  MathJax is on the cusp of a 1.0 release and we will update this library once it's final.

Answer (score 7):

<strike>Three</strike> <strike>Four</strike> Five observations:

- If one escapes a latex fragment using backticks (this is frequently needed in order to arbitrate between Markdown and the latex rendered) the latex piece gets colored in gray due to the stylesheet in a rather unsightly way.
- Display math using `$$` does not seem to work.
- It would be immensely useful if the preview of answers rendered latex too.
- Something's amiss with things like \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}, which gets rendered as $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. (Hmm, here it looks fine, but in [Group With an Endomorphism That is "Almost" Abelian is Abelian.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/group-with-an-endomorphism-that-is-almost-abelian-is-abelian/1157#1157) it doesn't)
- Editing a comment kills everything within dollar signs.

Comment: TeX markup is implemeted by making calls to http://chart.apis.google.com/... I wonder why that is better than having the client render?

Comment: It's not. I hope they switch to mathjax. I *do* see your 2 and 4: math within $$ ... $$ doesn't work (it keeps a dollar sign on each side and just displays inline), and on the question you linked to, even the / and 3 are in blackboard.

Comment: Okay, [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423/intuitive-reasoning-behind-the-chain-rule-in-multiple-variables/426#426) shows the behavior you describe for `$$`. But you can use `$\displaystyle ... $` for now as Qiaochu did [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540/what-is-the-riemann-zeta-function/832#832).

Answer (score 7):

If the formula is not complicated, besides <sup> and <sub> I also use character entities in html. Some examples:

bold &prod; displays as **∏**
bold &sum; displays as **∑**

in general, Greek letters are displayed by writing &letter; other symbols are

ℵ &alefsym;
∀ &forall;
∃ &exist;
∈ &isin;
∩ &cap;
∪ &cup;

Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) for the complete list of allowed characters. I know that this is not enough to write decent mathematics, but it's a start.

Comment: wow that works great. I've never thought that you can use html encoded symbols in stackexchange. I though only some tags like pre, sup, sub, br... work here

Comment: @mau: that link does not work anymore ...

Comment: I updated the link, this time using Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references.  I hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

I do believe that this is of utmost urgency, and should be first priority for any developers working on this site.

Comment: I doubt anything will happen during the beta, unless a lot of betas want the facility.

Comment: MathOveflow already has this feature, and I suspect that it shouldn't be very hard to make it work here as well.

Answer (score 4):

Is this thing on?
$\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_{i}
\end{equation}$

...yep!

$\begin{tabular}{r|c|l}
symbol & read as & example \
\hline
$\to$ & ``maps to" & $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Z}$ \
$\forall$ & "for all" & $\forall x \in E$
\end{tabular}$

... what environments are going to work here? (clearly not `tabular`)

**EDUT** Oh,  didnt read the comments.  Thanks guys for working on this!

Answer (score 3):

I vote for **[MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/)** to be used instead of jsMath if a Javascript library is decided over a server-side LaTeX image generator.

Equation rendering is [exceptional](http://www.mathjax.org/preview/preview-tex-examples/) over jsMath, and all major browsers are supported. (Even IE6!! See [Browser Compatibility](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/browser-compatibility/).) Most operating systems and browsers anti-alias the LaTeX, and the equations seem to fit in to the native look, whatever browser that may be.

Answer (score 3):

Is anyone else seeing the symbols as monstrously huge?

Answer (score 2):

Agreed. I think everyone is begging for this feature. It's been requested numerous times on Meta StackOverflow, the latest one specifically for Area 51/StackExchange being [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53436/implement-google-api-call-to-display-latex-as-inline-image).

Personally I would like to see [**jsMath**](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/) implemented on StackExchange sites. It's virtually trivial, a script reference simply needs to be added to the page.

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime, there's [Google Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/formulas.html).

edit: except that it doesn't appear to show up. :P

Comment: See my answer, I have added a script that uses the Google Chart API to some success.

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX rendering is needed, but I would like to see a server-side solution rather than a client-side solution such as jsMath. The biggest problem for me with jsMath is that it takes such a long time to completely load a web page on some popular MathOverflow questions. Often I have to simply disable jsMath or else the web browser consumes so much memory that my computer starts swapping pages of RAM to the disk.

What about adding a toolbar button to convert a LaTeX expression to an image using the [mathURL](http://mathurl.com/) service?

Answer (score 2):

I am running John Gietzen's awesome Greasemonkey script in my browser and everyone's TeX is showing up great - but **I am having a problem** composing TeX. Specifically, I seem to be completely unable to include addition signs in my formulas. This makes zero sense to me, can somebody explain?

For example: "P of x equals a x squared *plus* bx *plus* c" looks like: $P(x)=ax^2 + bx + c$

I have typed `$</code><code>P(x)=ax^2 + bx + c</code><code>$`

**EDIT**: [Isaac](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/72/isaac) has fixed the script, it looks like it's working pretty good now.

Comment: I was just experiencing the same problem.  I haven't looked into the script yet, but I suspect that it's because a + in url-encoding is an encoded space (i.e. there's some missing encode/decode step).

Comment: Here's my modified version of the script: http://pastebin.com/uVB1rEdf --I think I've fixed the plus-sign issue and I've also excluded the script from running on the edit page (which, at least for me, was making all TeX markup vanish entirely in the edit box).

Comment: @Isaac, @John Gietzen: Thanks to you both for implementing this *hugely important* workaround.

Comment: @Isaac:  The line "name == 'textarea'" is supposed to prevent it from interfering with the edit window...

Comment: @John: I didn't read through it enough to catch that.  For some reason, though, on Mac Chrome it was still eating the TeX in the textareas, which is why I added the exclude.  The change from `escape` to `encodeURIComponent` was the more important change, though.

Comment: How do I install this after downloading greasemonkey?

Comment: @Casebash: My answer at the top has a link to the Userscripts.org page.  There should be a big green "Install" button.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before, one option that doesn't involve a third party rendering service is [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/), the spiritual successor to jsMath. Here is a small [userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/82184) that inserts MathJax (currently hosted on my own web server, but presumably would be hosted by stack exchange on a permanent basis) into the head of math and meta.math.

You can use a number of math formats for display, like regular ol' TeX markup:

$P(x)=ax^2 + bx + c$

Or some more complex TeX formatting:

$\left( \sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k \right)^2 \leq \left( \sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2 \right) \left( \sum_{k=1}^n b_k^2 \right)$

And eventually, if Stack Exchange allows MathML to be inserted into pages, code like this:

```
<math display='block'><mrow><mi>x</mi><mo>=</mo><mfrac><mrow><mo>&#x2212;</mo><mi>b</mi><mo>&#x00B1;</mo><msqrt><mrow><msup><mi>b</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>&#x2212;</mo><mn>4</mn><mi>a</mi><mi>c</mi></mrow></msqrt></mrow><mrow><mn>2</mn><mi>a</mi></mrow></mfrac></mrow></math>
```

(something seems a little slow when loading MathJax here - it may be a configuration problem on my end. I will look into it later today. Reference [the official preview page](http://www.mathjax.org/preview/preview-tex-examples/) if you want a better idea of the latency with translating lots of TeX on a page with javascript - it's quick)

Comment: Installed in Chrome, worked for about 1 minute (rendered beautifully, if slow on the first load), then stopped working.  Page loads generate the initial "Loading" message at the bottom, briefly, but no subsequent messages and none of the TeX is rendered.

Comment: It didn't even occur to me to check in Chrome, doing so now...

Comment: Did you have any luck with it in Chrome?

Comment: It works for me. (Chrome 5 Mac)

Answer (score 1):

**Another temporary workaround:**

Use [LaTeXiT](http://chachatelier.fr/programmation/latexit_en.php) with [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) or any other image hosting service. To match the size of the body text, set the font size to 16 pt.